# Getting error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '='

Tags: python, flask, select, jinja2, rendering

i am trying to set select field choices using jinja in html but getting error. can someone help me with the mistake i am making in writing {{ seat_form.seat.choices = Available_seat_lst }} line of code. Error is showing on the same line. tried {% seat_form.seat.choices = Available_seat_lst %} and {%set seat_form.seat.choices = Available_seat_lst %} as well but not working

```
class SeatbookingForm(FlaskForm):
    seat = SelectField(label = 'Select Seat:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    date = DateField('Date', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    submit = SubmitField(label='Book Seat')
```

html Jinja snippet

```
<br>
{{ seat_form.seat.label() }}
{{ seat_form.seat(class="form-select") }}
{{ seat_form.seat.choices = Available_seat_lst }}
<br><br>
```

route return:

```
return render_template('seat.html', seat_form=seat_form, current_date=current_Date, next_date=nextDay_Date, avail_seats=Available_seats, booked_seatsbyuser=booked_seats, total_seats=total_seats, Available_seat_lst=Available_seat_lst, Available_seat_lst_next=Available_seat_lst_next)
```

seat_form.seat.choices = Available_seat_lst works fine in python but errors out when trying to use it in html Jinja

Answer (score 0):

Set the value before you call `seat_form.seat()` and don't use `{{  }}`. It's for printing values. Use `{%  %}` instead.

This should work:

```
<br>
{{ seat_form.seat.label() }}
{% set seat_form.seat.choices = Available_seat_lst %}
{{ seat_form.seat(class="form-select") }}
<br><br>
```

Comment: it did not work... TemplateSyntaxError
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'seat_form'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.

Comment: {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}

{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<body class="text-center">
    <div class="container" style="width: 25%">
        <form method="POST" class="form-signin" style="color:white">
            {{ seat_form.hidden_tag(
<input class="form-control" type="date" id="datepic" name="datemaxmin" min={{current_date}} max={{next_date}} value={{current_date}}>
            {{ seat_form.seat.label() }}
            {% seat_form.seat.choices=Available_seat_lst %}
            {{ seat_form.seat(class="form-select") }}
  </body>
{% endblock %}

Comment: Edited my answer, add `set` to set a variable